# How to run my .gif file only if mouse is hover on picture?

Tags: jquery, css

How to run my .gif file only if mouse is hover on picture?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pHcXa/

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="img_wrap" class="static">

   <img id="animated" src="database.gif">
   <img id="static" src="database.png">

<script type="text/javascript">


  $(function(){
    $('#img_wrap').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
         $(this).toggleClass('animated', 'static');

    })
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does one "run" a GIF?

Comment: @Diodeus I mean display gif file

Comment: @user2659960 updated answer now works more better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pHcXa/4/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#img_wrap').on('hover', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('animated').toggleClass('static');
    }, function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('animated').toggleClass('static');
    });
});
```

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 3):

or you can use css for doing this

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/parslook/pHcXa/3/

css

```
body {
    background-color:#282828;
}


.image {
    background: url(http://swish.wodip.opole.pl/forum/files/thumbs/t_spirala_157.png);
    width:300px;
    height:310px;
    background-size:300px;
}

.image:hover {
    background: url(http://www.laboiteverte.fr/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/gif-psychedelique-hypnose-animation-11.gif);
    width:300px;
    height:310px;
    background-size:300px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="image">

</div>
```

Comment: Even better than JS, though I'd still recommend having a copy of the gif in the DOM without it being displayed (or even programmatically loaded), given the fact gifs tend to be heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('#animated').hide();
var toggleImages = function(){
  $('#animated, #static').toggle();
};
$('#img_wrap').on('hover', toggleImages, toggleImages);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep the gif loaded in display none as preloading and change the img source on mouse over, so that the gif will start from its beginning (in case you display something which is not looping etc)

http://jsfiddle.net/pHcXa/2/

```
$('#static').on('mouseover', function() {
     this.src ='http://www.laboiteverte.fr/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/gif-psychedelique-hypnose-animation-11.gif';
})
$('#static').on( 'mouseout', function() {
     this.src ='http://swish.wodip.opole.pl/forum/files/thumbs/t_spirala_157.png';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, some people searching the same solution, will find this one worth:

```
<html>
<style>
#img_wrap{
    width:200px;height:200px; // set width & height as of your images' sizes.
    background:url("database.png") center center no-repeat;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="img_wrap" class="static">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#img_wrap').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'url("database.gif") center center no-repeat;');
});
$('#img_wrap').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css('background', 'url("database.png") center center no-repeat;');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```